# Unable to uninstall Atom System Image SDK from Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Each time I try and remove the x86 Atom System Image from my Android Studio, I am greeted with this message. The IDE log does not provide much data about what is causing the issue.

Is there something else that I may have installed that is causing me to be unable to uninstall this SDK?

I have removed all my AVDs from this machine.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out.

In my `~/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis/x86/` folder there was an `.installer` file that needed to be deleted.

Once I did that, I was able to remove the system image.